# $\{(x_n, y_n)\}^\infty_\mathrm{n=1}$ in $(X \times Y, d_3)$ converges to a point $(\overline x, \overline y)$ in $(X \times Y)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Suppose that $(X, d_1)$ and $(Y, d_2)$ are metric spaces. We can then form the Cartesian product $X \times Y$, which is the set of all ordered pairs of the form (x,y) where $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$. We can also introduce a metric $d_3$ on $X \times Y$ by setting $(\forall x_1, x_2 \in X)(\forall y_1, y_2 \in Y)$ $$d_3((x_1,y_1)(x_2, y_2)) = d_1(x_1,x_2) + d_2(y_1,y_2)$$

I'm trying to prove that a sequence in $\{(x_n, y_n)\}^\infty_\mathrm{n=1}$ in $(X \times Y, d_3)$ converges to a point $(\overline x, \overline y)$ in $(X \times Y)$ if and only if:

(1) the sequence $\{x_n\}^\infty_\mathrm{n=1}$ converges to $\overline x$ in $X$

(2) the sequence $\{y_n\}^\infty_\mathrm{n=1}$ converges to $\overline y$ in $Y$

I don't think you would have to verify that $d_3$ is a metric, but I have no idea where to even begin.

Comment: It's not hard to prove that $d_3$ is a metric given that $d_1$ and $d_2$ are, but if this is an introductory real analysis class, that may be expected.

Comment: My point was that I don't think verifying $d_3$ is a metric space is useful (or necessary) because it can be assumed from given info, as you said. This is based on ideas from undergraduate real analysis texts, not any specific problem.

Comment: Can you more specifically describe what you are asking?

Comment: You have a sequence $(x_n, y_n)$ in the cartesian product space $ (X \times Y, d_3)$ that converges to a point $(\overline x, \overline y)$. I'm trying to prove that this can only be the case if $(x_n)$ converges to $\overline x$ in $X$ and $(y_n)$ converges to $\overline y$ in $Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $ x_n \to \bar{x}$ and $ y_n \to \bar{y} $. Take your desired $ \varepsilon >0 $. By the two convergences there exist $ N_1, N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$ \forall n > N_1 \quad d_1(x_n, \bar{x}) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \\ \forall n > N_2 \quad d_2(y_n, \bar{y}) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} $$
taking $ N=\max\{N_1, N_2\} $, this means that we would have
$$ \forall n > N \quad  d_3\big((x_n,y_n), (\bar{x}, \bar{y})\big) = d_1(x_n, \bar{x}) + d_2(y_n, \bar{y}) < 2 \times \frac{\varepsilon}{2} $$
and therefore $ (x_n, y_n) \to  (\bar{x}, \bar{y}) $.

Conversely, suppose that one of the the two sequences doesn't converge to it's point, say $ \{x_n\} $ doesn't converge to $\bar{x}$. This means that there exists some $ \varepsilon_0>0 $ for which
$$ \forall N \quad \exists n > N \quad \mathrm{s.t.}  \quad d_1(x_n, \bar{x}) > \varepsilon_0 $$
but this means that we also have
$$ \forall N \quad \exists n > N  \quad d_3\big( (x_n,y_n), (\bar{x}, \bar{y}) \big) = d_1(x_n, \bar{x}) + d_2(y_n , \bar{y})> \varepsilon_0$$
since $ d_2(y_n , \bar{y}) $ is non-negative. And therefore $ (x_n, y_n) \not\to (\bar{x}, \bar{y})$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the sequence $\{(x_n,y_n)\}$ converges to $(\bar{x},\bar{y})$ in  $(X\times Y, d_3)$. Then given $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a posituve integer $N$ such that
$$
d_3((x_n,y_n),(\bar{x},\bar{y})=d_1(x_n,\bar{x})+d_2(y_n,\bar{y})< \varepsilon \quad \forall n>N.
$$
It follows that
$$
d_1(x_n,\bar{x})< \varepsilon \quad \forall n>N,
$$
and
$$
d_2(y_n,\bar{y})< \varepsilon \quad \forall n>N,
$$
i.e. the sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges to $\bar{x}$ in  $(X, d_1)$ and the sequence $\{y_n\}$ converges to $\bar{y}$ in  $(Y, d_2)$.

Now, suppose $\{x_n\}$ converges to $\bar{x}$ in $X$ and  $\{y_n\}$ converges to $\bar{y}$ in $Y$. Given $\varepsilon>0$, there exist positive integers $N_1$ and $N_2$ such that

$$
d_1(x_n,\bar{x})< \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \quad \forall n > N_1
$$
and
$$
d_2(y_n,\bar{y})< \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \quad \forall n > N_2.
$$

Let $N=\max(N_1,N_2)$. For all $n>N$, we have
$\displaystyle d_1(x_n,\bar{x})< \frac{\varepsilon}{2} $ and  $\displaystyle d_2(y_n,\bar{y})< \frac{\varepsilon}{2} $, and
\begin{eqnarray}
d_3((c_n,y_n),(\bar{x},\bar{y}))&=&d_1(x_n,\bar{x})+d_2(y_n,\bar{y})\cr
&<&\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\cr
&=&\varepsilon
\end{eqnarray}
i.e.
$$
d_3((c_n,y_n),(\bar{x},\bar{y}))<\varepsilon \quad \forall n>N
$$
meaning that $\{(x_n,y_n)\}$ converges to $(\bar{x},\bar{y})$ in $X\times Y$.